# How to start another app from a library module class?

Tags: java, android

I have an library module "ops" which i have successfully imported in my "FirstApplication".This library module contains and interface "MathOps" and its implementation using a class "MathPosImple".
I am trying to implement a method "LaunchSecondApp()" in "MathPosImple" that will open another application "SecondApplication".

Here is the code for the method to launch the second app

```
    private void launchSecondApp(Context context,int num1,int num2,String type) {



    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction("com.ezetap.firstapplication.MainActivity"); // <packagename.login>
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("num1", String.valueOf(num1));
    bundle.putString("num2", String.valueOf(num2));

    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("add")){

        bundle.putString("type", "add");

    }else {
        bundle.putString("type", "sub");


    }

    sendIntent.putExtra("data", bundle);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(sendIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}



public class MathOpsImple extends AppCompatActivity implements MathOps  {

int REQUEST_CODE = 10000;

public static String result;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void doOps(Context context,int num1, int num2,String type) {




    launchSecondApp(context,num1,num2,type);


}



private void launchSecondApp(Context context,int num1,int num2,String type) {



    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    //Need to register your intent filter in App2 in manifest file with same action.
    sendIntent.setAction("com.xcz.firstapplication.MainActivity"); // <packagename.login>
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("num1", String.valueOf(num1));
    bundle.putString("num2", String.valueOf(num2));

    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("add")){

        bundle.putString("type", "add");

    }else {
        bundle.putString("type", "sub");


    }

    sendIntent.putExtra("data", bundle);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
      startActivityForResult(sendIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle bundle = data.getBundleExtra("datasend");
            result = bundle.getString("result");

        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

}

but it is showing error as :

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4507)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4464)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
at com.ezetap.ops.MathOpsImple.launchSecondApp(MathOpsImple.java:54)

I can't find why it is showing this error. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this? I have never used an custom android library. I have created the ops library and then created the activity "MathPosImple" in my "ops" library. Now i need to start the second app using this library activity only.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions i have passed the context of the calling activity as a parameter to the method. However it is now showing the following error (I have edited the question and errors produced). startActivityforResult() can not be attached with this context parameter. So now again showing error

Comment: try writing a Utils Method if using java or extension method in kotlin.

Comment: @Andy sorry! showing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The error occurred because startActivityForResult() method in library class is not getting the activity thread that wants to start it since i am starting it using the MainActivity of app module.
So i had to initialise the MainActivity in the library module class using a constructor and then used that activity instance to start the startActivityForResult() method.

Here i initialised MainActivity (which is providing the intent) of app module with in the library module

```
Activity activity;


public MathOpsImple(Activity activity){
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

Using this activity variable i am starting the startActivityForResult()

```
        if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        activity.startActivityForResult(sendIntent, requestCode);
    }
```